# Can I DNS A Record Point to any IP?

Tags: networking

1)

Would it be possible to have a DNS A record point to a non-existent / supposed to be non-existent IP?

Essentially is there anything that *prevents* a DNS record from linking to anything?

Ex. Could someone go into a DNS record and change it to point to malicious things. ex. would it be possible for someone to point www.company.com --> 1.1.1.1 which is the IP for a malicious attacker?

2)

From this:

Ex. http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/http.html

Those bogons. Would it be possible to have a DNS record point to one of them and some how 'fake' that they are this IP ?
I'm thinking yes via IP Spoofing?
Would there be someway for a website to emulate that it is actually a different IP address via a combination of DNS and IP trickery?

- What prevents someone from saying that a certain DNS links to any IP. is there any sort of checking?
- Could a DNS be used to hide the actual service provider and somehow provide service from IP (A) but 'say' it's providing service from IP (B). As DNS, I believe, is only supposed to tell you the IP to connect to I don't think this is possible yet I'm not sure.

Thanks,

Requesting for reopen: Why is this not a valid question? This from my standpoint is a valid cybersecurity question that I face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP addresses always exist. They are just numbers. What might happen is that a name is resolved to an address because there is a dns record doing so, whilst there is no server listeing at the address. Or even no system using that address.

If it's possible to 'use' such circumstances to whatever depends on a million things, so there is no way to give an answer without a clear question.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents a A record from pointing to any random set of numbers?

Comment: Well the record has to be registered, that is an administrative part. In the end it is a question of quality of service and terms of service as offered by the dns provider. I myself already managed to get 'pretty interesting records' registered.

Comment: you say "the record has to be registered" but to who? From my understanding one can host their own name server. Who verifies the authenticity of the registration records - there are easily hundreds of registrations per day.

Comment: Certainly you can host your own dns server. Then you are the service provider. But noone will use your dns server, right? People use dns providers they trust, typically those of their broadband provider or some big public service.

Comment: Trustworthy dns service providers accept only registration requests done by legitimate domain owners. And since the name resolution process sends clients to the dns server responsible for the "higher instance", e.g. the top level domain a requested name belongs to, the clients are handed down to the dns server responsible for this name. No one will ask your dns server.

Comment: Can you not host your own autonomous system and somehow broadcast it? What about if your dns server does not have a record, it would recursively look for another server without one - can you not make it look at yours? 

Well how do you validate legitimacy? What if you are the dns server responsible for one ...? Ex. Can I have a a.b.c and c passes it down to b. and I own b and then I'll say b maps to 1.1.1.1 though in actually I'm somehow providing service from 1.2.2.2

Comment: I think it makes time if you spend a little time to understand how dns name resolution actually works. Really, I am not trying to sound pedantic here. It is just that you appear to guess what might happen, which rarely is a good idea in a deterministic science like IT.

Comment: have a suggestion where to look? :D i've read a few rfcs... but not yet the specific DNS protocol one I think